# How do I read elements from to lists alternately?

Tags: java

Hi I have 2 list defined:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> questionsList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<JRadioButton> answersList = new ArrayList<JRadioButton>();
```

I try to read questions and answers in format like that:

```
1st Question 
  answer1
  answer2

2nd Question 
  answer1
  answer2
etc.
```

So 1st question is read from list **questionsList** then I want to read from another list **answersList** all answers to that question and etc.

In questionsList I read data from mysql and they are saved in JLabels in format like: 
1. Question one
2. Question two
 etc

In answersList I read data from mysql and they are saved in JRadioButtons in format like: 
answer1
 
answer2
etc

My code so far:

```
    int height = 0;

        for(int i1 =0; i1<questionsList.size(); i1++)
        {   
              client.insideFillPollPanel.add(questionsList.get(i1)).setBounds(20, 20+150*i1, 480, 14);

            height = 20+150*i1;  

            for(int i2 =0; i2<answersList.size(); i2++)
            client.insideFillPollPanel.add(answersList.get(i2)).setBounds(20, 50+30*i2, 480, 14);



        }
```

How do i solve it to be display like 1st format I showed so question then asnwers question and asnwers?

Comment: Not sure what is your problem

Comment: @VikasNalwar, It seems like a design problem...idk

Comment: yeah design problem, because all answers are displayed under the first question and answers are permeate through other questions and are not assigned to question they belong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to create a `Question` class which contains both the question and all answers belonging to that question and then, instead of having

```
ArrayList<JLabel> questionsList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<JRadioButton> answersList = new ArrayList<JRadioButton>();
```

You use

```
ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

(as a side note: It is considered good practice to program against interfaces, so instead of storing the questions in a `ArrayList<Question>` I suggest you go for a `List<Question>`.)

---

For example:

```
class Question {

    JLabel questionLabel;
    List<JRadioButton> answers;

    public Question(String q, String... ans) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @aioobe ok sounds good can you give me some more light about that? some schema I should go forward ?

Comment: @takeit, not sure what you mean. I added a stub class for you if that helps.

Comment: @aioobe yeah this is what I wanted some example on how to do it thanks